# Koszul formula applied to divergence

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

On a Riemannian manifold $(M, g)$ of dimension $n$, for a point $x$ on $M$ and a basis $\{U_i\}$ for $T_xM$ which is orthonormal with respect to $g$, we have the formula $$\operatorname{div} V = \sum_{i=1}^n g(\nabla_{U_i} V, U_i)$$ for the divergence of vector field $V$ at $x$, where $\nabla$ here is the Levi-Civita connection (see proof of Proposition 3.1.1 in Hsu's *Stochastic Analysis on Manifolds*). The [Koszul formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Riemannian_geometry#The_Koszul_formula) allows us to write \begin{align*} g(\nabla_{U_i} V, U_i) = \frac{1}{2}&\left[U_i(g(V, U_i))+V(g(U_i, U_i))-U_i(g(U_i, V))\right. \\ &\left.+g([U_i, V], U_i)-g([U_i, U_i], V)-g([V, U_i], U_i)\right] \end{align*} Given that $g(U_i, U_i)$ is constant and that $[U_i, U_i] = 0$, this seems like it should simplify down to $$g(\nabla_{U_i} V, U_i) = g([U_i, V], U_i)$$ so we could equivalently write $$\operatorname{div} V = \sum_{i=1}^n g([U_i, V], U_i)$$ Firstly, are these in fact equivalent? If so, are there any reasons for preferring one form of this definition to another?

Comment: Sure, this is correct. However, I think the first formula makes the definition clearer/more palatable, because it's the trace of the $(1,1)$ tensor field $\nabla V$. This is an almost straight-forward generalization of the definition first encountered in $\Bbb{R}^n$ as $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial V^i}{\partial x^i}(x)$ which is none other than the trace of the Frechet derivative $DV(x)$, or equivalently the trace of the Jacobian matrix $V'(x)$.

Comment: oh btw, you should assume that the $U_i$'s are vector fields defined on an open neighborhood of the point $x$, and that they are orthonormal with respect to $g$ on the entire open set for this to make sense.

Comment: Oh and there's also the geometric definition: on an oriented (pseudo) Riemannian manifold with volume form $d\mu_g$, we can define $\text{div}(V)$ to be the unique smooth function such that $\mathcal{L}_V(d\mu_g)=\text{div}(V)\,d\mu_g$. If you want to drop the orientability assumption, then you have to think of $d\mu_g$ as a scalar density. In all these cases, the definitions agree, and it's "straightforward" to show that in a local coordinate chart, $\text{div}(V)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial\left(\sqrt{|g|}\,V^i\right)}{\partial x^i}$; this is the Voss-Weyl formula.